# Equivalent for minPointLength of HighChart in google chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have a dynamic column chart done in google chart. My values are like below.
[-1436403, -1123447, -794032, -147734, 12859, 722352, 88102, 1382678, 1931450, 255630, 3230913 ]
Since there is a big difference btn min and max values, min value is not showing. [image: please see the image]

I saw an option in highchart to set min height for a bar. Can anyone suggest equivalent for the same in google chart or any other solution for my problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if `vAxis.viewWindow.min` will help. You can try it. Othervise `vAxis.logScale` could help.

Comment: logScale cannot be used with -ve values. viewWindow... :|

Comment: Yes, sure. I completely forgot about negative values.

Comment: There is no option to do what you want, but you can fudge your data a bit to make the bars appear larger.  I wrote an example fiddle showing different ways to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/b4yCL/